# Is there any way to get the file content which is triggring azure blob trigger?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

So I have created a Azure blob trigger, and it is working fine as soon as I put some file or create some directory on the blob the trigger happens.

**Question:** Now I can not figure out how can I get the same file content which causes the blob trigger.

I can get the files using Azure storage library, but I am going to upload lots of files on the blob and want to do some processing on the file which has just written on the blob.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks pretty straightforward from the example documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---java-example

```
@FunctionName("blobprocessor")
public void run(
    @BlobTrigger(name = "file",
                 dataType = "binary",
                 path = "myblob/{name}",
                 connection = "MyStorageAccountAppSetting") byte[] content,
    @BindingName("name") String filename,
    final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info("Name: " + filename + " Size: " + content.length + " bytes");
}
```

The content gets passed in as a byte array.

Comment: It’s not that simple actually I am not able to get the content tho content is there as [] bytes

Comment: You need to convert the byte array to whatever type it is, if it is a plain text file you can read it as a string.

Comment: I did tried that is not working for me but thanks for the help

Comment: No worries, show some code if you want more help with it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way we can get the file content is

```
@FunctionName("BlobTrigger-Java")
    public void blobTriggerWhenUploadFile(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "data/{name}", dataType = "binary", connection = "StorageConnection") String content,
            @BindingName("name") String name,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
```

This is working code

```
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

/**
 * Azure Functions with Azure Blob trigger.
 */
public class BlobTriggerFunction {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when a new or updated blob is detected at the specified path. The blob contents are provided as input to this function.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @FunctionName("BlobTrigger-Java")
    public void blobTriggerWhenUploadFile(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "data/{name}", dataType = "binary", connection = "StorageConnection") byte[] content,
            @BindingName("name") String name,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        
        context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob. Name: " + name + "\n  Size: " + content.length + " Bytes");
//String result=new String(content,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        context.getLogger().info("The upload file content is: " + result);

    }
}
```